# Cannot get hashcode of a parent and set it as a child's variable

Tags: java, swing, object, hashcode, super

I have a class called `Doctor`, and a class `Patient` that extends it. In my application, a Doctor logs in with a username and password and he registers a bunch of Patients.

The Doctor ID has a `hashcode()` method that I know works (auto-generated by Eclipse and was tested before as generating unique hashcodes based on usernames), as does a Patient.

I have a variable called `patientdID` and `patientduserName`, and `dID` and `duserName` (the doctor's ones). and getters and setters for both the doctor and patient.

When a patient is registered, I want to generate a file of patient fields which include the doctor who registered the patient, and the patient registered, via the toString() method of Patient. However, right now, the patientdID is not set as the dID, and the patientdID always stays at 31 (it is not really the true hashcode of the doctor).

When a patient is registered, the following code is called (relevant parts inserted):

```
patient = new Patient();
doctor = new Doctor();

patient.setpatientdID(doctor.getdID());
patient.setpatientdUserName(usernameField.getText());
```

The getters for these fields for the patient are:

```
public void setpID(int pID) {
        this.pID = pID;
    }

public int getpatientdID() {
    return patientdID;
}


public void setpatientdID(int patientdID) {
    this.patientdID = patientdID;
}

public String getpatientdUserName() {
    return patientduserName;
}
```

And for Doctor are:

```
public int getdID() {
        return dID;
    }

    public void setdID(int dID) {
        this.dID = dID;
    }

    public String getDuserName() {
        return duserName;
    }

    public void setDuserName(String duserName) {
        this.duserName = duserName;
    }
```

And constructors for Doctor are:

```
public Doctor() {
        this.dID = this.hashCode();
        this.duserName = duserName;
        this.dpassWord = dpassWord;
    }
```

And for Patient are:

```
public Patient() {
        super();
        this.pFirstName = pFirstName;
        this.pLastName = pLastName;
        this.pDob = pDob;
        this.pAddress = pAddress;
        this.pPhoneNumber = pPhoneNumber;
        this.pBillingCycle = pBillingCycle;
        this.pMedicalCondition = pMedicalCondition;
        this.pComments = pComments;
    }
```

Finally, the toString() method of patient is:

```
public String toString() {
        return patientdID+","+patientduserName+","+this.hashCode() + "," + pFirstName + "," + pLastName + "," + pDob
                + "," + pAddress + "," + pPhoneNumber + "," + pBillingCycle
                + "," + pMedicalCondition + "," + pComments;
    }
```

I have tinkered and hacked through this to understand but would prefer an answer which told me how to structure my code, given my objective, and what I should be doing e.g. calling super somewhere etc.

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost -- the Patient class should **NOT** extend Doctor. Period. This is not and never can be an *is-a* relationship but instead is a *has-a* relationship: a patient *has a* doctor (or more than one). So give Patient a Doctor field, if they have one doctor or a `List<Doctor>` if they have multiple doctors, and fill the field as needed. Then you can extract information from the field as needed.

As side recommendations:

- I would not use hashCode for ID's. Also I would avoid using ints or any other numeric type for this, since an ID is not something that you would do numeric operations on, such as adding or subtracting. I'd use a String instead.
- Your parameterless constructors that are setting fields to themselves are useless. In this situation, this, `this.pFirstName = pFirstName;` will just set pFirstName to whatever the class initially defined it as, perhap `null` even. Use parameters when you need to.
- OK to use inheritance to give Doctor and Patient a shared base class, say called `Person`. This can have a name field, an id field, and any other shared fields, with the appropriate constructors.

For example, something like:

```
// a base class that abstracts what is shared by Doctor and Patient
public class Person {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    // .... etc

    public Person(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

```
public class Doctor extends Person {
    private List<Patient> patients = new ArrayList<>();

    public Doctor(String id, String name /* add any additional params here*/) {
        super(id, name);
        // ...  set fields here
    }

    public boolean addPatient(Patient p) {
        return patients.add(p);
    }

}
```

```
public class Patient extends Person {

    private Doctor doctor;

    public Patient(String id, String name, Doctor doctor /* add any additional params here*/) {
        super(id, name);
        this.doctor = doctor;
        // ... set additional fields here
    }

    // you can get the Doctor's id from its object
    public Doctor getDoctor() {
        return doctor;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured this out using hashcodes, but appreciate the answer above.

The username needed to be set before a doctor hashcode was created (as the hashcode relies on it). So, I needed:

```
doctor.setDuserName(usernameField.getText());
patient.setpatientdID(doctor.hashCode());
```

I also removed references to `super()` in the constructor for a patient but I don't think this makes a difference, as I am not overriding the doctor IDs.

I agree with you on the inheritance point. My `patientdID` and `patientdUserName` variables within `Patient` are similar to when you say "give the patient a Doctor field".

Comment: No, I'm afraid that they're not similar. Inheritance misuse in this situation is dangerous and brittle. See changes to my answer including code.